# Is this verse present in the Māitrāyaṇa-saṁhitā́ found in the Tāittirīya-saṁhitā́?

Tags: reference-request, yajur-veda, samhita

[image]

I vaguely remember this hymn in the Tāittirīya-saṁhitā́, I'd like if anyone could tell me where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching TITUS and Svadhyaya Mandal Pune I found the vājapeyādhvaryave rathasamskārā hymn in Tāittirīya-saṁhitā́ 1.7.7

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do note it might occur in more than 1.7.7 specifically, in the Tāittirīya-saṁhitā́.

Comment: It's also found in Vājasaneya 9.1, 11.7, and 30.1

Comment: It is in mahāsatobr̥hatī and the Svadhyaya Mandal Pune lists the r̥ṣi as Soma.